# d3.js line().x(x).y(y)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am studying the bezier curve from [this](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/) demo, in the beginning it defines a series variables like this

```
var w = 250,
    h = 300,
    t = .5,
    delta = .01,
    padding = 10,
    points = [{x: 10, y: 250}, {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 100, y: 0}, {x: 200, y: 250}, {x: 225, y: 125}], 

    bezier = {},
    line = d3.svg.line().x(x).y(y),
    n = 4,
    stroke = d3.scale.category20b(),
    orders = d3.range(2, n + 2);
```

I have no idea what does `line = d3.svg.line().x(x).y(y)` mean, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the fantastic [d3js documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line) on `d3.svg.line()`.

`d3.svg.line()` returns a function that can be called with input data points and returns a SVG Path describing a line.  The x/y values of the items in the input are determined by the values passed to `line().x()` and `line().y()`, which could be functions or constants.  Normally they'll be a `d3.scale()`.

For example,

```
var data = [{x: 1, y: 3}, {x: 50, y: 100}, {x: 100, y: 0}];
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]).range([0, 20]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 10]);
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d){ return x(d.x); })
  .y(function(d){ return y(d.y); });

line(data);
```

Will return "M0.1,0.3L5,10L10,0", which can be assigned to the `d` attribute of an `svg:path` and describes a line going through the points 0.1,0.3  5,10 and 10,0.